# Batch transpose a comma separated file

Tags: batch, text-editing

I'd like to reorder a file with a batch from this schema:

```
Default Web Site;anonymousAuthentication    
Default Web Site;windowsAuthentication
Daisy;anonymousAuthentication
Daisy;windowsAuthentication
```

to this schema:

```
Default Web Site;anonymousAuthentication;windowsAuthentication
Daisy;anonymousAuthentication;windowsAuthentication
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please check out our code formatting with the `{}` button. Makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your data

```
$ cat  t13.dat
Default Web Site;anonymousAuthentication

Default Web Site;windowsAuthentication

Daisy;anonymousAuthentication

Daisy;windowsAuthentication
```

Here's how to generate your result

```
$ perl t13.pl t13.dat
Daisy;anonymousAuthentication;windowsAuthentication
Default Web Site;anonymousAuthentication;windowsAuthentication
```

Here's the script

```
$ cat t13.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %values;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  next if /^\s*$/; # ignore empty lines
  my ($category, $value) = split /;/, $_, 2;
  $values{$category} .= ';'.$value;
}

for my $category (sort keys %values) {
  print "$category$values{$category}\n";
}
```

You seem to be using Windows, install [Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) first.

---

If your data doesn't contain blank lines and you are ok with slightly more cryptic solutions:

```
$ perl -lanF\; -e'$v{$F[0]}.=";".$F[1]; END{print "$_$v{$_}" for keys %v}' t13.dat
Daisy;anonymousAuthentication;windowsAuthentication
Default Web Site;anonymousAuthentication;windowsAuthentication
```